# how do I iterate an Azure DevOps Pipeline through multiple configurations?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a multi-stage Azure DevOps pipeline that works great for one configuration.  I would now like to have it loop through multiple configurations to build artifacts and copy them to multiple locations.  My first attempt at this provides radio buttons for my two configurations (which makes sense, since there is no actual looping code) but then fails  in the Release stage with no errors but a message reading simply

**"Parent pipeline used these runtime parameters:"**

And then:

**configuration: "Texas"**

This is the YAML:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4
# Gus' first working multi-stage pipeline

trigger: none
 

pool:
  #windows-latest worked until Microsoft changed it to windows-2022 and i got
  #"The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found."  error
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'  


  
parameters:
- name: configuration
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: Texas
  values:
  - Texas
  - Arizona

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: ${{ parameters.configuration }}


 
 

stages: 
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build


    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script:  |
        
          cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)
    #git reset --hard 7314280f2 


    #- task: UseDotNet@1
    #  inputs:
    #    packageType: 'sdk'
    #    Version: '4.6.1'
    #    includePreviewVersions: true

    #without this first one, bad things happen!!
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
        
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: Release
  displayName: Release
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  
  
  jobs:


      - deployment:
        displayName: Release
        environment: 
            name: QA
            resourceType: VirtualMachine
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:

              steps:
              #- script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.configuration}}
 
              - task: CopyFiles@2
                inputs:  
                  SourceFolder: '$(Agent.WorkFolder)\1\drop'
                  Contents: '**\*.zip'
                  OverWrite: true
                  TargetFolder: 'C:\QA\Web Sites\${{ parameters.configuration }}'
```

What might be the cause of the failure?  And what would be a good strategy to get this to iterate through all the configurations instead of providing radio buttons in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I iterate an Azure DevOps Pipeline through multiple configurations?

You could loop through parameters instead of the variables,like:

```
parameters:
- name: 'configuration'
  type: object
  default: 
  - Texas
  - Arizona


steps: 
- ${{ each p in parameters.param }}:
  - checkout: self

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
     msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(p)'
```

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters) for some more details.

Comment: this sort of code doesn't work at all for multi-stage pipelines.  i want the whole thing to iterate, not just the Build stage. but maybe this is impossible.  also, and perhaps i am asking too many questions, this doesn't address the issue of why the Release stage doesn't produce errors and also fails to run.

Comment: One further point:  when I tried your example, it doesn't actually iterate. It just prints the value of the parameter I choose. (When I start the build, I am presented radio buttons for Texas and Arizona).  I'm hoping to find a way to simply iterate through the configurations without having to choose.